# unit ball of dual space in R

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I want to sketch the unit ball in the dual of $R$, the unique linear formes defined on $R$ have the forme $f(x)=ax$ with $a$ is reel,  so
$${B^*} = \{ f(x) = ax/\sup |ax| < 1{\text{ for |x| = 1\} }}$$
i fond that the elements of this ball are the function of the forme $ax$ with $|a|<1$ ? Is that true ? thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right! What is the $\sup |x|$ over the set with $|x| = 1$?

Comment: $sup|x|=1$ I gess